# A "truly" generic function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, existential-type

Suppose I have a compound data type -

```
data M o = M (String,o)
```

Now, I can define a function that works for ALL `M` irrespective of `o`. For example -

```
f :: M o -> M o
f (M (s,o)) = M (s++"!", o)
```

However, `f` is not really as general as I'd like it to be. In particular, using `f` in an expression fixes the type of `o` so I cannot use `f` again with a different type of `o`. For example the following does not typecheck -

```
p f = undefined where
  m1 = M ("1", ())
  m2 = M ("2", True)
  m1' = f m1
  m2' = f m2
```

It produces the error - `Couldn't match expected type 'Bool' with actual type '()'`

Surprisingly, if I don't provide f as an argument and instead simply use the global definition of f then it compiles and works fine! i.e. this compiles -

```
p = undefined where
  m1 = M ("1", ())
  m2 = M ("2", True)
  m1' = f m1
  m2' = f m2
```

Is there a particular reason for this? How can I work around this problem i.e. define a function `f` that can be applied to all `(M o)`, even when the `o` varies within the same expression? I'm guessing existential types come into play here but I just can't figure out how.

Comment: Why would you make M a tuple? How ugly.

Comment: something is "forall" by by default, something else is not. you may see this texts : http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types

Comment: @monadic, it's really just a minimal example that reproduces the problem I was facing in my actual code (which is significantly more complicated).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler cannot infer the type of p properly. You'll have to give it a type signature:

```
p :: (forall o. M o -> M o) -> a
```

This is a rank 2 type, so you'll need a language extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}
```

or

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
```

Read more about it here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Rank-N_types

Comment: Thank you! Adding that type signature worked. I figured it had something to do with the forall keyword but didn't know about RankN types. Looks like I have some reading to do!

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a particular reason for this?

Indeed, there is one. To say it in one sentence: type inference will not work properly if one lifts the restriction of the HM system that lambda arguments must be monomorphic.

Simon Peyton Jones has devised a type checker that extends HM and allows higher rank polymorphism. But in such cases, explicit type annotations are required. See Sjoerds Answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `f` in the scope of the function `p f` is not the same as the top level function `f`.  It is whatever function is given as the argument when `p` is called.  Since you didn't give `p` a type signature, the compiler has to infer what `f` is from how you use it.  Your first use implies that `f :: M () -> M ()`, which means `p :: (M () -> M ()) -> a`.  As someone else said, you have to give `p` an explicit signature using `forall` to do what you're trying to do.